# Zend: Remove Special Characters from String

Tags: php, zend-framework

How do you remove special characters from an array key that is a string? I am receiving XML from the United States Postal Service and they are trying to encode TM and TradeMarks in the XML unescaped. So when I show shipping costs from them; it appears as though a lot of gibberish is inside the select box I created.

When I try this -

```
 foreach($responseUSPSsimple as $name => $amount) {
        strip_tags($name);
    echo $name . '<br />';
    }
```

I get this --

```
Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup>
Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Hold For Pickup
Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Sunday/Holiday Delivery
Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Flat Rate Boxes
Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Flat Rate Boxes Hold For Pickup
Express Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Sunday/Holiday Delivery Flat Rate Boxes
```

Can any one help me to remove the  section from that output?

Comment: At the very least, `strip_tags($name);` needs to be `$name = strip_tags($name);`

Comment: $name = strip_tags($name); did not work. Doesn't look like it made any changes to the echo.

Comment: Any html tags in `$name` would likely not show up as you would see the html.  But as it was, `strip_tags($name)` did nothing to name since it never assigned the result to any variable.

Comment: Looks like CDATA if that is XML. You should consult the documentation what exactly is in that field. Also you should show as well the XML so it is more clear what this is about. Are you using SimpleXML?

Comment: Thank you Ignacio for your reply. It was super helpful. I wish I could up vote it.

Comment: All you're trying to do is remove everything between XML tags from the  array keys, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the output you posted is shown in the browser. Based on your comment made that `$name=strip_tags($name)` didn't work, your original strings have already html entities in encoded format, hence `strip_tags` can't remove such tags. Try below.

```
foreach($responseUSPSsimple as $name => $amount) {
    $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($name));
    echo $name . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find something more precisely fitted for your problem you could always use the sledgehammer method to remove all xml tags from the output:

```
foreach($responseUSPSsimple as $name => $amount) {
    $newName = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>.*?<[^>]+>#', '', $name);
    echo $newName . '<br />';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d2615f35cb5d07a689e0e2dea7a99d483816ce5)